# Android Gallery View - How to set resource?

Tags: android, interface, view

I am new to Java programming / Android development - but I have been working through a few examples and have been trying to build a "mix-and-match" app with 3 scrolling galley views.

I have created the relative layout with 3 gallery views, and have defined 3 arrays to contain a list of images.

My problem is that I can't seem to get the ImageAdapter to set the correct image resource for each gallery view (it duplicates the same images across all 3 galleries).

If I can just post the relevant sections of code:

```
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    Gallery gTop = (Gallery) findViewById(R.id.gallery_top);
    Gallery gMid = (Gallery) findViewById(R.id.gallery_mid);
    Gallery gEnd = (Gallery) findViewById(R.id.gallery_end);

    gTop.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));
    gMid.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));
    gEnd.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));
}
```

Then another class sets the resources (hardcoded):

```
 public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ImageView i = new ImageView(mContext);
        i.setImageResource(mEndThumbIds[position]);
        i.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
        i.setLayoutParams(new Gallery.LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)
        );
        return i;
    }
```

How can I remove this hardcoded link and check to see what object is calling getView and set the image resources accordingly?

Thanks, Alex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about you add a new constructor to your adapter so that it reads `new ImageAdapter(this, Type.END)` or `new ImageAdapter(this, Type.BEGIN)`?

Of course you would define a `enum` to make the switch.

Then, in the constructor simply check which one is requested and set the list.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I think I did something similar to what you said, but Java/Android is very new for me (I'm a PHP guy). My constructor looks like this:
public ImageAdapter(Context c, Integer[] gName) {
   mContext = c;
   mGalleryName = gName;
}

I then set the Gallery view adapters:
galleryHead = (Gallery) findViewById(R.id.GalleryHead);

Hope that helps someone else just finding their way!